# AttributeUsage in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have an action and two attributes that are applied to it. I want that if first attribute return true, then second attribute doesn't execute.

```
[First]
[Second]
public ActionResult Display()
{
    return View();
}
```

In other words, can I skip executing `[Second]` attribute if `[First]` returns true?

Comment: Save the first attributes result somewhere (session, or something) and then check that in the code for the second attribute?

Comment: yes this is the way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easy to create cases inside `[First]` implementation?
i.e.

```
[First(Second=true)]
public ActionResult Display()
{
    return View();
}
```

If first attribute returns true then don't execute second, else execute it.